# I am not able to execute a program which includes user input of a integer inside an else if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

When user enters 1,2 or 3, the program exits without scanning for the quantities inside the else if statements block.

How to scan inside a if or else if statement?

```
if (num==4)
{
    printf("exiting");
    goto end;
}

else
{
    if (num=='1')
    {
        printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*kmstomiles;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);
    }  

     else if (num=='2')
    {
         printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*inchestofeet;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);

    }
    else if (num=='3')
    {
        printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*cmtoinches;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);
    }
```

Comment: `1` and `'1'` are different. `1` is integer one while `'1'` is character one i.e `49` (ASCII value of `'1'`). Change the condition `num=='1'` --> `num == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code,

```
if (num==4)
{
    printf("exiting");
    goto end;
}

else
{
    if (num==1)
    {
        printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*kmstomiles;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);
    }  

     else if (num==2)
    {
         printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*inchestofeet;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);

    }
    else if (num==3)
    {
        printf("enter the value of the first unit\n");
        scanf("%f",&first);
        second=first*cmtoinches;
        printf("the value of the second unit is %f",second);
    }
```